# How to copy Data from one class to another

Tags: c#, .net

Imagine that i have classes like below

```
public class A
{
    public int  a;
    public B [] b;
}

public class B
{
   public int a;
   public int b;
}
-------------------------
public class C
{
    public int  a;
    public D [] b;
}

public class D
{
   public int a;
   public string b;
}
```

How to copy data of Class C to A ?
it's simple but because of list (B[] , D[]), i don't know?

Comment: how about [Automapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper/)?

Comment: Without simply setting the values of C to the values A?  Like *a.a = c.a*?

Comment: @StinkyTowel : !!!! please check data type and that filed is list

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: Create properties and constructor inject your values.

Comment: @StinkyTowel : it's simple but because of list (B[] , D[]), i don't know?

Comment: In B you b is int in D your b is string how you will map it ?

Comment: @SajjadZare Please don't post the same comment multiple times mentioning everyone ever. Especially with a nonsense comment like that. If you had actually read the link I provided, you would know that we expect you to at least attempt to write some code to fix your own problem. SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: @mybirthname  : ! exactly this is my problem

Comment: Again you can make it if you create property stringB of type string in B class which return b.ToString() and you can map it this way.

Comment: I read it several times, actually, very carefully. It's not like there's much there to read... like nothing explaining "any difficulties that have prevented from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep it simple and answer your question, here is the code needed.
The anticipated issues? I've commented the line I am most skeptical about, I hope you're considering another design because this design somewhat resembles a recipe for disaster.

This answer however should set you on the right path, you can implement further null & sanity checks.

```
public class A
{
    public int a;
    public B[] b;

    public A()
    {

    }
    public A(C c)
    {
        a = c.a;
        b = c.b.Select(p => new B
        {
            a = p.a,
            b = int.Parse(p.b) // What if p.b isn't a valid, parsable integer?
        }).ToArray();
    }
}

public class B
{
    public int a;
    public int b;
}

public class C
{
    public int a;
    public D[] b;
}

public class D
{
    public int a;
    public string b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the class public and make your variables properties with

```
public int a { get; set; }
```

You can now call C.a from class A

Comment: check question now please

Comment: I see it. I guess I'm confused about what you really want to do if this doesn't solve your problem

Comment: it's simple but because of list (B[] , D[]), i don't know?

Comment: You don't know what? You will need to create a D[] to store it in there. There's too many possible things you want to do with you explaining there's no way to help you